# how to switch between click and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dut to I put show item One and Two in the same place so it needs to display as when clicking One it shows the result one and clicking two it close the One and show TWO. But how can I make it?

I got some trouble in how to switch this...
it can only click to show and click to hide.....
also, the slideToggle can only display "fast" and cannot work for "slow"
I don't know why...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ClickNShow1').click(function() {
    $('.Hide1').slideToggle("fast");
  });
  $('.ClickNShow2').click(function() {
    $('.Hide2').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ClickNShow1">click item 1</div>
<div class="Hide1" style="display: none;">show item ONE</div>

<div class="ClickNShow2">click item 2</div>
<div class="Hide2" style="display: none;">show item TWO</div>

<div class="ClickNShow2">click item</div>
<div class="Hide2" style="display: none;">show item</div>
```

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: when clicking the first item it shows but when clicking the second item....the first item is still there and it needs to click once than can close the first one.
how can I make this directly switch?

Comment: @Oly : share your complete code

Comment: @Oly 
: what you mean by this ___slideToggle can only display "fast" and cannot work for "slow" I don't know why.___ ?

Comment: `fast` stands for `200ms` and `slow` for `600ms` if you want to make more slower then provide the time in milliseconds

Comment: $('.ClickNShow1').click(function() {
    $('.Hide1').slideToggle("slow");
  });

Comment: @Oly :  try `$('.Hide1').slideToggle(2000);`

Comment: $('.Hide1').slideToggle("6000"); I tried this, but nothing changed. I also add transition-duration: 0.5s in CSS but this not works as well. Am I put it to the wrong place?

Comment: @Oly :  remove the quotes bro ..... `$('.Hide1').slideToggle(6000);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read on [ask] and format your question to more clearly state what you want us to answer. Elongated threads of conversation that have a solution, belong in Answers too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to slide up all the other divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // get all divs
  var divs = $('.Hide1,.Hide2');

  // attach click handler to both 
  $('.ClickNShow1,.ClickNShow2').click(function() {
    //  get div next to the clicked eleemnt
    var div = $(this).next('.Hide1,.Hide2');
    // toggle the div
    div.slideToggle("fast");
    // slideup all other divs
    divs.not(div).slideUp("fast");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ClickNShow1">click item 1</div>
<div class="Hide1" style="display: none;">show item ONE</div>

<div class="ClickNShow2">click item 2</div>
<div class="Hide2" style="display: none;">show item TWO</div>

<div class="ClickNShow2">click item</div>
<div class="Hide2" style="display: none;">show item</div>
```

FYI : Provide duration as a number value in milliseconds, to make it much slower, for eg: `slideToggle(2000)` - this provides 2sec.

Taken [from docs](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) :

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively.

Comment: can I let all my items use the same class to show and hide? then I just need to put clickNshow1 and Hide1 in all the items. I just tried two items it can nice to switch. But I am not sure this may have any problem or not?

Comment: @Oly : yes you can

Comment: In this case, how can I show the first item when loading, then through the clicking to switch to others?

Comment: @Oly :  Nope., check docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display